# Binary code in jQuery lib

Tags: jquery, binary

I am setting up a local installation of a wordpress site on my computer with docker. I got it up and running but the jquery script is failing. After some research i found that javascripts stops when it encounters weird stuff in the jquery (v1.11.3) library. I have tried to analyse the weird, and I think it is binary code. I got the files after dowloading it noramlly with the ftp-client Transmitt (os x).

This is the weirdness:

```
m.isArray(b)?b=b.0��0����������P��@P��e--)
```

I haven't found the same thing in a fresh copy of the jquery lib. But I might have missed out on something.

Can anyone tell me what is is?

Answer (score 1):

It is because file is written on window or other environment, which is other than Mac. In Mac environment file storage is different.

Different OS uses different file structure and character format.

[image: Encoding]

[image: OS Mode]

Comment: Thanks.
But wouldn't the ftp-client handle this. Kind of like the same way a server is sending jquery scripts on requests?

Comment: you have to check character encoding in your FTP or maybe you have to open it in editor and set proper configuration. see my attached screenshots.

Comment: I switched to "binary mode" and it looks like it  downloaded everything without errors.